# Why won't the mute key LED light go out at all?

Tags: sound, multimedia

After i upgraded from 20.10 to 21.04 on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th the mute key LED light is on at all times. The key work just fine and mutes the sound with the normal OSD icon, but the LED light is on. I can not find a way to get it to go out and work normally. Anything I can do in this regard?

Comment: This is odd. I have the same notebook and do not have this issue with 21.04. The one difference is that I did a fresh install of 21.04 (so that I could use ZFS) … 

Comment: Well, it's still on. I hate to have to do a fresh install just for that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I am having a Jabra USB headphone dongle plugged into my laptop at all times since I use my Jabra's all the time for conferences and music. It's a USB-C dongle that my headphones connect to when I turn them on. I just unplugged the dongle. hit the mute key and the LED went out. Then I put the dongle back in and now I can toggle mute/unmute with the LED coming on and going off.  I had that dongle inserted during the update from 20.10 also. It's so small and in use all the time so I had totally forgotten about it!